# Sparklyr using case_when with variables

Tags: r, dplyr, sparklyr, dbplyr

Sparklyr fails when using a `case_when` with external variables.

Working Example:

```
test <- copy_to(sc, tibble(column = c(1,2,3,4)))
test %>%
  mutate(group = case_when(
                   column %in% c(1,2) ~ 'group 1',
                   column %in% c(3,4) ~ 'group 2'))
```

Fails with `Error: Can't extract an environment from NULL`

```
test <- copy_to(sc, tibble(column = c(1,2,3,4)))
group1_cols <- c(1,2)
group2_cols <- c(3,4)
test %>%
  mutate(group = case_when(
                   column %in% group1_cols ~ 'group 1',
                   column %in% group2_cols ~ 'group 2'))
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try unquoting the variables:

```
test %>%
  mutate(group = case_when(
    column %in% !!group1_cols ~ 'group 1',
    column %in% !!group2_cols ~ 'group 2'))
```

For more info check out the `dplyr` programming vignette http://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html